# Unable to do partial word search in Solr 8.6.0

Tags: solr

I have few records with _fiscalyear value as 2019-2020 but I am unable to search the text 2019 or 2020.  I can search 2019-2020.

The query I am using is https://solr.xyz:8983/solr/mycore/select?q=2019&qf=_fiscalyear&defType=edismax

below is the _fiscalyear configuration in the schema file

```
<field name="_fiscalyear" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="false" />

<copyField source="_fiscalyear" dest="text_en"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding

```
<filter class="solr.EdgeNGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="15" /> under 

      <analyzer type="index">
```

fixed the isssue

Comment: That won't work for 2020 will it? If your tokenizer doesn't split on `-` already, then you'll end up with `20`, `201`, `2019`, `2019-`, `2019-2`, etc. as tokens, and no `2020` by itself.

Comment: you are right.  Then how do I handle this at indexing level?

Comment: using NGramFilterFactory instead of EdgeNGramFilterFactory solved the problem.  Now I can 2020 as well

Comment: If you only want to search for the whole number (this will give results even if you just search for `20` - if that's what you want, leave it as it is), you'd be better off using a tokenizer that splits on `-`, or a WordDelimiterGraphFilter instead that does the same.